# How to move text to center of ListBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have almost tried everything but for some reason it is not working

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,30,5,10">
    <TextBlock Text="View Options" FontSize="25" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewOptions}" Margin="10">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="35" Margin="20" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Above XAML give me

[image]

How to move the `textblock` to `center` of `listboxitem`?

Comment: can you please have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746433/how-to-add-list-item-selector-to-listbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,30,5,10">
    <TextBlock Text="View Options" FontSize="25" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewOptions}" Margin="10,30,10,10">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                 <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="35" Margin="20" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the *HorizontalContentAlignment* to center

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,30,5,10">
<TextBlock Text="View Options" FontSize="25" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Red" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewOptions}" Margin="10">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="35" Margin="20" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you post what `PhoneTextNormalStyle` looks like?   Is there alignment properties in it? Or remove PhoneTextNormalStye and see if it works.  (I tried this code and it works for me)

Comment: It doesn't work even after removing PhoneTextNormalStyle. PhoneTextNormalStyle is built-in resource in Windows Phone

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it worked.  Two possible differences:

- My data source was a simple `List<string>`.
- I removed the references to your styles (i.e. `PhoneTextNormalStyle`).

Are you binding to simple data?

Does `PhoneTextNormalStyle` specify left-alignment?

Comment: My itemssource is also List<String>. Even if I remove the style the problem still comes