# How to add List item Selector to ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am currently working on Windows Phone 8 Application, i have a ListBox with TextBlock with border as a background to it, when i click on the item in the list box there is no indication to the user that he as selected that item, how to add selected item color to it?

And also i need to select multiple items in the ListBox, Which ever the item is selected its background color should be changed.

Below is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ListBoxLayout" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4,0,0,0">
    <ListBox Name="listBox" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
             SelectionChanged="TopicListboxSelectionChanged"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Name="AnswerCellBack" Tap="AnswerCellBack_Tap" Margin="0,0,0,4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border Name="borderColor" Background="#FFF2F4F7">
                        <TextBlock Name="text"
                               Width="456"
                               Padding="10,20,10,20"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
                               Style="{StaticResource AnswerTextStyle}"/>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>              
</Grid>
```

Comment: so for changing the background color, you have two main option - create custom style for your longlistmultiselector or you can create simple converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SelectionMode property to enable multiple selection in listbox.
Or you can use LongListMultiSelector from Windows Phone toolkit.

To change the background color of selected item, change the style template of listbox as mentioned here,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx.

Find this line in the ListBoxItem Style, and change it to your color

```
<Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
```

You can declare styles in App.xaml under the Application.Resources tag.

Or like these 2 ways in your page.

First Way.

```
<ListBox Name="lstbx">
<ListBox.Style>
    // Your Style
</ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Second way.

Declare the styles under the tag phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources, like this.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Test.Test"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyListStyle"  TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        //your style
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<ListBox Name="list1" Style="{StaticResource MyListStyle}"
//....
```

Comment: i tried to add the style in my page with the name "<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">" after adding i get this error "prefix vsm is not defined"

Comment: Vsm prefix is not necessary.. you can use <visualstatemanager> directly for wp8 styles.

Comment: Ok, i have added, but its below my border is on top of that, how to fix this ?

Comment: Ok , i will show the screen shot on how it looks with that you can figure it out

Comment: Please see my edit, how my list item looks  like, and also i want both the boder color and the seleted item color, how i have set my stly for my list box is : in XAML  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"

Comment: Its the image when i select the item.

Comment: Since you have not set the "BorderBrush" and "BorderThickness" whereas you set the "Background" for your Border in the DataTemplate, the background color is visible. Try to set "BorderThickness=1" and "BorderBrush=somecolor", and give different color to your Background other than the BorderBrush color.

Comment: You mean to say i need add "BorderThickness=1" and "BorderBrush=somecolor" to my Border ?

Comment: Yes. Give different colors to the background and borderbrush of border in listbox datatemplate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47397/discussion-between-goofy-and-stackamar)

Comment: can you please help me on this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794443/change-the-listbox-item-border-style